# "source not available" but only under certain conditions

Tags: c#, html, razor, visual-studio-2017, asp-net-mvc-1

[image]I have an strange error in one of the views I am trying to load.

In one of my views I have about 3600 lines of code on that view, as soon as I try to load that view it shows me an error:- **source not available**, and as soon as I reduce lines of code (about 200 lines from anywhere on the view) it does not show any error.

Is there explanation for this?

Comment: Try to check if `Debug -> Windows -> Exceptions -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions` is enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried it and it still shows me the same error. I did not find any relevant information about it on the net..maybe this is a bug that only exists in VS2017